# Scanf is mutating my number

Tags: c, scanf, stdio

I have a program that grabs a user input number and adds the appropriate ending (1st, 11th, 312th, etc)
So I gave it to my friend to find bugs/ break it. 
The code is

```
    int number;
    printf("\n\nNumber to end?: ");
    scanf("%d",&number);
    getchar();
    numberEnder(number);
```

when 098856854345712355 was input, scanf passed 115573475 to the rest of the program. 
Why? 115573475 is less than the max for an int.

Comment: Where exacltly is 115573475 in input

Comment: where is your numberEnder Function's Code?????

Comment: @user2848254 Why would that matter? The issue occurs immediately after `scanf` as far as I can tell.

Comment: 115573475 is 98856854345712355 mod (2^32).  This is not behaviour you should rely on. The behaviour is undefined by the C standard, which means that the compiler is allowed to just output code that works for valid inputs, and not care about what happens when invalid inputs are given.

Comment: 115573475 is stored in 'int number' after scanf reads 098856854345712355.

Comment: @MattMcNabb Do you have a reference for your "undefined behavior" comment?

Comment: @ooga ,C99 7.19.6.2p10 "If...the result of the conversion cannot be represented in the object, the behaviour is undefined."

Comment: there's some discussion [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.std.c/03tnRCrdYOU) along with the behaviour of various compilers; I concur with @KeithThompson 's analysis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`098856854345712355` is too big of a number for int.

```
long long number;
printf("\n\nNumber to end?: ");
scanf("%lld",&number);
getchar();
numberEnder(number);
```

---

The answer to why you get a specific garbage answer is [GIGO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_in,_garbage_out). The standard doesn't specify the result for bad input and it's implementation specific. I would hazard a guess that if you apply a 32 bit mask to the input, that's the number you would get.

---

Just out of curiosity, I looked up an implementation of [scanf](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-1456.1.26/libkern/stdio/scanf.c).

It boils down to

```
…
                                res = strtoq(buf, (char **)NULL, base);
…
                                    *va_arg(ap, long *) = res;
…
```

Which should truncate off the high-bits in the cast. That would support the bit-mask guess, but it would only be the case for this implementation.

Answer (score 4):

INT_MAX is typically (2^31) -1 which is ~2 billion... 
... if you look at `98856854345712355 & 0xffffffff` you will find that it is 115573475

Comment: `INT_MAX` is `(2**31)-1`, which is ~2 billion.

Answer (score 3):

The C99 standard states in the `fscanf` section (7.19.6.2-10):

> ...the result of the conversion is placed in the object pointed to by
>   the first argument following the `format` argument that has not already
>   received a conversion result. If this object does not have an
>   appropriate type, or **if the result of the conversion cannot be
>   represented in the object**, the behavior is undefined [emphasis added].

This is true in C11 as well, though `fscanf` is in a different section (7.21.6.2-10).

You can read more about undefined behavior in [this excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4105123/774071), but it basically means the standard doesn't require anything of the implementation. Following from that, you shouldn't rely on the fact that today `scanf` uses the lower bits of the number because tomorrow it could use the high bits, `INT_MAX`, or anything else.

Comment: this is absolutely true in theory... but the second that I discover that my std library replaces overflows with 0xdeadbeef is the day I find a new library...